# How to prevent scrollview in UITableView when user swipe gesture down two touches?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want when user swipe direction down on UITableView, I do some stuff and table is not scrolling. How I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want your `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to fire alongside the UITableView's `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, you just need to set the delegate of your swipe gesture and implement

`- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *) otherGestureRecognizer`

then return `YES`.

If you want to interrupt the tableview's pan gesture, you probably can't use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to do so, since it doesn't actually fire until the user has swiped a certain distance.

You can, however, use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to fake that behavior if you need. I was able to get something similar:

```
#pragma mark UIViewController lifecycle

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didPan:)];
    [panner setDelegate:self];
    [panner setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:panner];
}

#pragma mark custom swipe response

- (void) didSwipe
{
    NSLog(@"SWIPED!");
}

#pragma mark UIPanGestureRecognizer response

- (void) didPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    [self cancelGestureRecognizer:self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer];

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

        if (translation.y > 20)
        {
            [self didSwipe];
            [self cancelGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark UIGestureRecognzierDelegate implementation
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *) otherGestureRecognizer
{
    //NOTE: blindly returning yes in this case is usually a bad idea. You should check the recognizers here. 
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark UIGestureRecognizer stuff that should be in a category and not this file.

- (void) cancelGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.enabled)
    {
        [recognizer setEnabled:NO];
        [recognizer setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

That said, in most cases it makes for a far better user experience just to use a pan gesture and make whatever animation/transition/interaction based on the distance they've panned (that's the `CGPoint translation` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
```

Comment: That's incomplete. Apparently OP wants to detect a two finger swipe down on the table view.